# PHP $_POST not inserting into mysql db after certain length

Tags: php, mysql

I've the following PHP executable, which is executed after a form is submitted.

```
<?php
{
mysql_connect("localhost","root","mypass");
mysql_select_db("mydb");
$myinput= $_POST['myinput'];
$result=MYSQL_QUERY("INSERT INTO mydb (myinput)".
"VALUES ('$myinput')");
mysql_close();
}
?>
```

Its working with short phrases, and numbers (approx 10 characters). But if I want to insert 150 character it just creates a blank line in the table.

The table has the following values:
Type: LongText (I only need alphabetic characters, no numbers)

I see nothing in syslog , no errors there.

EDIT: I've noticed that if the input has a "whitespace/blankspace" in the end it will be posted no matter what the size is.

FE

This doesnt work, isnt imputed: "This is a long inputed text with xxx characters"

This works (Is inputed): "This is a long inputed text with xxx characters " (Notice the blankspace in the end)

EDIT2: My current php executable (welcome.php)

```
<?php
{
mysql_connect("localhost","root","my_pass");
mysql_select_db("my_db");
$variable = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['variable']);
$result=MYSQL_QUERY("INSERT INTO `mydb_table` (`variable`) VALUES ('".$variable."')");
mysql_close();
}
?>
```

and this is the form which is inputing the data

```
<div id="create" ng-controller="Controller as vm" ng-show="accounts.mode === 'do-seed'">
        <form action="welcome.php" method="post" id="seed-form" name="accountSeedForm">

          <button id="generate" class="Button fade" ng-click="vm.generateSeed()" type="button">CREATE SEED</button>
          <br/><br/>
          <div class="form-field">
            <label for="variable">variable</label>
            <br/>
            <textarea id="variable" rows="4" name="variable" class="InputR" xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx></textarea>
            <span class="clipSpan" tooltipster tooltip-theme="tooltipster-theme1" title="Copy the seed to the clipboard." data-clipboard-target="#xxxxSeed" data-clipboard-message-success="xxxxxx successfully copied to clipboard" ></span>
            <br/>
          </div>
          <br/>

          <div class="wPop-content">
            <div>ADDRESS
              <br/>
              <span>{{vm.displayAddress}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="wButton fade" type="submit">REGISTER ACCOUNT</button>
          <span class="divider-2"></span>
          <button class="wButton fade" type="reset" ng-click="vm.back()">BACK</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which one is best for you.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: You have an obvious error in your SQL. Fix it and you'll get values in your DB but you'll also be open to SQL attacks. Your choice which is worse.

Comment: But it works, only for short inputs but it works... I know about the security issues. Im just trying to learn and cant figure why is not working with long inputs

Comment: This issue is with your database definitions..  Check your schema.  You'll have to increase the number of characters for that column.  Example : varchar(255)

Comment: Also have a look at how you have designed your table infrastructure. What kind of fields are you table rows? TEXT can contain large chunks of data. VARCHAR(10) for example allows up to 10 characters.

Comment: ALTER TABLE mydb ALTER COLUMN myinput VARCHAR (150) NULL;

Comment: Nope, i changed to VARCHAR and increased to (255) but I keep getting a blank line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your table schema varchar then i think your filed limit set 10; so update

```
ALTER TABLE mydb ALTER COLUMN myinput VARCHAR (150) NULL;
```

if you do not want to null then

```
ALTER TABLE mydb ALTER COLUMN myinput VARCHAR (150);
```

and also update your query

```
$myinput = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myinput']);    
$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mydb` (`myinput`) VALUES ('".$myinput."')");
```

hope you can insert 150 , if you want to insert more then update VARCHAR  length

Comment: its strange because it still doesnt work. A blank line is created and nothing more. Even if I put VARCHAR (255). The same happened to me when i was using a post in a txt file. Only short inputs worked

Comment: please check update answer , if not work then inform me then try other process

Comment: I found the FAIL. It only works when the inputed text ends with a "space" . No clue why is that happening. But if theres no "blank space" " " . In the end, it doesnt inputç+

Comment: ok can you give me your table then i can check it with your text file which not working

Comment: $myinput = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myinput']); 
try this , check my update anwer

Comment: mm.... still not posting. Isnt there anyway to force a whitespace after the input?

Comment: yes you can do that

Comment: give me the text file which need to add or demo file

Comment: Updated with the requested info

Comment: i did not find any issue in your code but if you want to add whitespace after input filed then 

$myinput = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myinput']);    
$myinput = $myinput .' ';

Answer (score 0):

I thing you  should check the column size and type. use this

```
ALTER TABLE mydb ALTER COLUMN myinput VARCHAR (255);
```

Comment: The comments on the question can tell you that the asker has tried that and it didn't work. I suggest reading the [answer] page, it contains useful tips on giving great answers.

Comment: Ive already done that, but doesnt seem to work.